# Google Sheets API: Reading a cell and saving it to a variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to find how to read a Sheets cell and save it to a variable I can output later in a form app's textbox. I'm sure the answer is obvious, but all I'm finding are ways to do it in a console app. I'm assuming it's essentially declaring a variable and defining it as the read method and eventually converting that to a string that the textbox can use. But I can't figure out what the correct way to do it is.

Comment: Have your tried this?
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values

Comment: Yes but everything I see there doesn't work when I try to output it to a form textbox

Comment: If you can post what you have done so far, maybe it will be helpful to figure out whats happening.